# how to pass values from a php script to another dynamically?

Tags: php, mysql, simplepie

i want to pass a url value from a php script to another.I have a database in which i have stored some feeds.I have given some weight values to these feeds and a php script grabs a feed url randomly based on their weights.I want to take the feed url which has been grabbed by the script and then pass this url in another php script where it will be parsed with simplepie in order to show its content.

I am posting the codes of the two files right here:

this is the first script which grabs randomly the feed
http://pastebin.com/2ciQ87Es
this is the second script in which i want to pass the value and makes the parsing of the feed
http://pastebin.com/eN5qG29e

Have you something to recommend??
thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you an empty page (empty body, nothing outputted) for your first file? Do you know that you don't NEED to have Html on your php pages at all?

Comment: i used html in my first page in order to auto-refresh the script at a specific time,because i need to have a different url after  that time.

Comment: You could do an auto-refresh on the other page too? No?

Comment: No,but i use the second page as my basic page where the css is used and i call jquery.

Comment: I have just understood what you meant.You mean that the autorefresh could happen in the second page only,right?But then an new value could be produced by the first scipt?

Answer (score 2):

Would a $_SESSION not suffice?

In the first script:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['session_name'] = 'value';
```

In the second script:

```
session_start();
print $_SESSION['session_name'];
```

---

On second thoughts, could you not pass the value in a query string, to the second page.

```
second-page.php?key=value
```

Comment: i did not used any session because i am not having a login system in order different users have access to the feeds.I want to make an rss scroller where the feed url is going to be grabbed randomly every 10 minutes for example and showing its feeds.And why i have difficulties in passing the value is that i don;t use any form to pass the values or any link(in this situation with jquery) to click.I hadn;t thought to use sessions for the reason i expalined before.

Comment: Could you not simply append the ?feed_id=id to the URL that you use to get the feeds?

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap grabbing the feed url from the database in a function, and just include that file like any other php file, and then call that function.

```
//// feedgrabber.php
<?php
function grabber(){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `feeds`";

    //takes all the feed that are declared
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $data   = array();
    while($output = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $data[] = $output;                  // assigns feeds to an array called $data, one after the other, in they go!

    }

    return randomchoice($data);            // finds a random feed by calling the function
}
?>
```

and then on the page where you need it:

```
require('feedgrabber.php');
$feed = grabber();
```

Comment: My friend i tried your approach and i think is the one till now that works best.But i have an issue...In the debugger i can see that everything works great.But i don't see anything in the div where the feeds are supposed to be shown...This implementation passes the values dynamically to the final script because i have to do that dynamically...